# gitolite hooks not found

Tags: git, hook, gitolite

I'm having trouble running some scripts with the POST_CREATE hook on gitolite3.

I've red the documentation on [non-core programms](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core.html) and how one can use the gitolite-admin repo to manage those. So far so good. So I went ahead and

- Uncommented the LOCAL_CODE variable inside .gitolite.rc to point to a /local subfolder inside the gitolite-admin repo
  `LOCAL_CODE                =>  "$rc{GL_ADMIN_BASE}/local",`
- Added a [script](https://gist.github.com/schnell18/8f31feb03e211c6fa4f1) to run with the POST_CREATE hook

  ```
   POST_CREATE                 =>
   [
       'SetHead.sh',
       'SetHead',
       'local/SetHead.sh',
       'local/SetHead',
       'local/hooks/SetHead.sh',
       'local/hooks/SetHead',
       'local/hooks/common/SetHead.sh',
       'local/hooks/common/SetHead',
   ],
  ```
- Ran gitolite setup --hooks-only
- Created a new repository

Sadly the script doesn't seem to work or isn't even found?
Any time I push the gitolite-admin repo to create a new repository I get the following warnings

```
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'SetHead.sh' (not found or not executable)
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'SetHead' (not found or not executable)
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'local/SetHead.sh' (not found or not executable)
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'local/SetHead' (not found or not executable)
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'local/hooks/SetHead.sh' (not found or not executable)
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'local/hooks/SetHead' (not found or not executable)
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'local/hooks/common/SetHead.sh' (not found or not executable)
remote: WARNING: skipped trigger 'local/hooks/common/SetHead' (not found or not executable)
```

/edit
Ok, apparently I got the paths wrong. The full path to the file on the server is

```
'/home/gitolite/.gitolite/local/hooks/common/SetHead.sh'
```

But this doesn't work either. Running the script directly on the server works as expected. I found a symlink to the script inside each repositories own hook folder. Does that mean it should work?

/edit2
Out of curiosity I've just put the script inside the /local/commands folder and enabled it by putting it's name in the ENABLE list in the .gitolite.rc file. For some reason this immediately worked...

Answer (score 1):

Finally... placing the script in /local/triggers worked. I got this idea from a book called "Gitolite Essentials" where they also use the triggers subdirectory for scripts triggered by POST_CREATE.

Why? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [documentation insists](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/non-core.html) on providing the full path, I would test with:

- full path in `LOCAL_CODE` (without relying on `$rc` substitution)
- making sure `SetHead.sh` is in that path, with the same case (uper/lowercase)
- making sure `SetHead.sh` is executable (chmod 755)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the full path might look like? I'm not a git expert, but from my understanding of how git internally works it's not like the script inside the repository is an actual file on the server?

Comment: Ok, I should have red the docs more carefully. The scripts get copied to /.gitolite/local/. That's the path I should have used.

Comment: Ok, now everything seems to be correct, but i still get the same warning. Executing the script on the server directly works... I don't get it.

Comment: I was not referring to any git-related path, but any path of your choice.